# loop through returned json using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, cycle

I am getting image and hyperlink information returned in the  JSON. I'd like to use the cycle plugin if possible.

Example:    `[["1.jpg","http:\/\/www.this.net\/"],["2.jpg","http:\/\/www.that.net\/"],["3.jpg","http:\/\/www.what.com/l"]]`

When my html page is first loaded it will already have this:

```
<div id="container"><a id="changeLink" href="o.html" target="_blank"><img id="changeImage" src="100.jpg" /></a>
```

Using the returned JSON, I'd like to loop through the image paths/links and update the changeLink and changeImage elements every 4 seconds. After it's reached the end, I'd like for it to repeat.

When page is loaded:

```
<a id="changeLink" href="http://www.this.net" target="_blank"><img id="changeImage" src="1.jpg" /></a>
```

After 4 seconds:

```
<a id="changeLink" href="http://www.that.net" target="_blank"><img id="changeImage" src="2.jpg" /></a>
```

After 8 seconds:

```
<a id="changeLink" href="http://www.what.com" target="_blank"><img id="changeImage" src="3.jpg" /></a>
```

After 12 seconds:

```
<a id="changeLink" href="http://www.this.net" target="_blank"><img id="changeImage" src="1.jpg" /></a>
```

After 16 seconds:

```
<a id="changeLink" href="http://www.that.net" target="_blank"><img id="changeImage" src="2.jpg" /></a>
```

After 20 seconds:

```
<a id="changeLink" href="http://www.what.com" target="_blank"><img id="changeImage" src="3.jpg" /></a>
```

And so on.

Comment: Are you saying you want to perform an infinite loop?

Comment: what have you tried? and do you mean you want to display one image for some time, then display another, and then loop?

Comment: SB, 

I want to start out with one image, then loop through the image paths in the returned JSON. I also want to link the images with the corresponding hyperlinks in the returned JSON.

<a id="changeLink" href="link.html" target="_blank"><img id="changeImage" src="image.jpg" /></a>

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would like to take the returned JSON, use it to generate `<img>` elements in the DOM with the `src` attibute pointing to the URLs in the JSON and then apply functionality to cycle through the images.

This can be achieved using, for example, the **[cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)**. Something like the following should work. *Note: untested*

```
   $.getJSON('jsonArray.php', function(data){
      var imgs = $.map(data, function (e, i) {
          return $('<img>').attr('src', e[1] + e[0]);
      });
      $('#container-for-imgs')
          .append(imgs)
          .find('img')
          .cycle({
              fx: 'fade'
          }); 
   });
```

**EDIT:**

In response to the comment, I think you would like to do something like this. You will ned to be more specific if I have misinterpreted

```
   $.getJSON('jsonArray.php', function(data){
      var change = ['changeLink', 'changeImage'],
          anchors = $.map(data, function (e, i) {
              var anchor = $('<a target="_blank" >').attr('href', e[1]).attr('id', change[0] + i);
              return $('<img>').attr('src', e[0]).attr('id', change[1] + i).appendTo(anchor);
          });
      $('#container-for-elements')
          .append(anchors);
   });
```

Comment: Close. Sorry, I didn't do the best job explaining. I'd like to cycle through the href, src attributes in the returned JSON.
Ex:

<a id="changeLink" href="link.html" target="_blank"><img id="changeImage" src="image.jpg" /></a>

Comment: when you say cycle through, what do you mean? Do you mean loop through the array and construct an `<a>` element with the second item in each array in the outer array and construct an `<img>` element with the first item of each array in the array?

Comment: I tried explaining things better in the edited version of the original post. You know how to do what I want to do. I am sorry I am so bad at explaining this.

Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: I think from what I have given, it should provide you with enough to get the outcome that you would like. Personally, I would load all of the images into the DOM and cycle through them; changing one image element's src attribute may cause a delay the first time that image is downloaded.